# Elegant Algorithm for finding Maximal Point of Cubic B-Spline Basis Function?

Tags: algorithm, spline, bspline, cubic-spline

Right now, I'm currently implementing a (potentially non-uniform) B-Spline Curve. One feature that I would like to have is the ability to know where on the curve a control point has the most influence. From my understanding, this is equivalent to solving the maximal point, `u`, of it's associated B-Spline basis function: `N(i, p, u)`. (where `i` is the index of the control point, `p` is the degree, `u` is the parametric parameter of the curve).

Given a non-decreasing knot vector `U`, let the i-th B-Spline basis function (of degree `p`) be defined as follows (from: [https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-basis.html](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-basis.html)):
[image]

and a B-spline curve as (from: [https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve.html](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve.html)):
[image]

From my understanding, the possible maximal points for a b-spline basis function are at the endpoints of its domain, as well as when its derivative is zero.

The derivative is as follows ([https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-derv.html](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-derv.html)):

[image]

For this question, let's only handle cubic b-spline curves (degree `p = 3`). And let's notate `u_in` as `u_(i+n)` (e.g. `u_i0` -> `u_i` .... u_i3 -> `u_(i+3)`.

The domain of `N(i, 3, u)` is `[u_i0, u_i4)`.

From my understanding, the derivative `N'(i, 3, u)` is defined piecewise based on each of it's knot spans: `[u_i0, u_i1)`, `[u_i1, u_i2)`, `[u_i2, u_i3)`, `[u_i3, u_i4)`.

Here are my derivative calculations for each of the knot spans (assuming that `u_j` < `u_(j+1)`, otherwise that knot span is ignored) :

**`[u_i0, u_i1]`:**

[image]

For this knot span, the derivative equals zero at `u = u_i0`.

**`[u_i3, u_i4]`:**

[image]

For this knot span, the derivative equals zero at `u = u_i4`.

**`[u_i1, u_i2]`:**

[image]

This knot span is a more complicated, so I'll solve for `N(i, 2, u)` and `N(i + 1, 2, u)` separately.

[image]

[image]

I plugged these two terms back into the original equation, and then had wolframalpha solve for `u` in terms of `u_i0`, `u_i1`, `u_i2`, `u_i3`, `u_i4`. What got returned to me is this beast:

[image]

where `t = u`...`u_j = u_ij`.

**`[u_i2, u_i3]`:**

[image]

Once again, solving for `N(i, 2, u)` and `N(i + 1, 2, u)` separately.

[image]

[image]

I plugged these two terms back into the original equation, and then had wolframalpha solve for `u` in terms of `u_i0`, `u_i1`, `u_i2`, `u_i3`, `u_i4`. What got returned to me is this beast:

[image]

where `t = u`...`u_j = u_ij`.

..........

So, in totality, my current algorithm is to get the possible maximal points for `u`. These include all knot span endpoints `{ u_i0, u_i1, u_i2, u_i3, u_i4 }`. They also include the values of `u` for which the derivate equals zero (taken from the equations above).

After getting all these points, I actually calculate the value of the basis function and return the `u` which gives me the highest basic function value.

The derivative equations between knot spans `[u_i1, u_i2]` are quite complex, and I'm not sure how to extend this to a higher degree. Does anyone know of a more extensible, elegant solution?

Thanks!